# python - presto - timestamps and decimal(38,18) returned as strings?

Tags: python, hive, sqlalchemy, presto, pyhive

Why are presto timestamp/decimal(38,18) data types returned a string (enclosed in u'') instead of python datetime/numeric types?

## presto jdbc:

select typeof(col1),typeof(col2),typeof(col3),typeof(col4),typeof(col5),typeof(col6) from hive.x.y

## result is

timestamp   timestamp   bigint  decimal(38,18)  varchar varchar

```
desc hive.x.y
#result is
for_dt  timestamp   NO  NO  NO  NO  1
for_d   timestamp   NO  NO  NO  NO  2
for_h   bigint  NO  NO  NO  NO  3
value   decimal(38,18)  NO  NO  NO  NO  4
metric  varchar(2147483647) NO  NO  NO  NO  5
lat_lon varchar(2147483647) NO  NO  NO  NO  6

attempt 1
#python
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
engine = create_engine('presto://u:p@host:port',connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': 'mypem'}})
result = engine.execute('select * from hive.x.y limit 1')
print(result.fetchall())
#result is
[(u'2010-02-18 03:00:00.000', u'2010-02-18 00:00:00.000', 3, u'-0.191912651062011660', u'hey', u'there')]

attempt 2
#python
from pyhive import presto
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

req_kw = {
'verify': 'mypem',
'auth': HTTPBasicAuth('u', 'p')
}

cursor = presto.connect(
host='host',
port=port,
protocol='https',
username='u',
requests_kwargs=req_kw,
).cursor()

query = '''select * from x.y limit 1'''
cursor.execute(query)
print cursor.fetchall()
#result is
[(u'2010-02-18 03:00:00.000', u'2010-02-18 00:00:00.000', 3, u'-0.191912651062011660', u'hey', u'there')]
```

Comment: The option 2 specified in the current answer is what you need to use, not sure why it has not been accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are getting from your sql query comes from the database in that format.

You have two choices

1. Map the Data Yourself (Write Your Own ORM)
2. Learn to use the ORM

**Option 1**

Note I've just hardcoded your query result in here for my testing.

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

# 2010-02-18 03:00:00.000
dateTimeFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"

class hivexy:
    def __init__(self, for_dt, for_d, for_h, value, metric, lat_lon):
        self.for_dt = for_dt
        self.for_d = for_d
        self.for_h = for_h
        self.value = value
        self.metric = metric
        self.lat_lon = lat_lon

    # Pretty Printing on print(hivexy)
    def __str__(self):
        baseString =  ("for_dt: {}\n"
                       "for_d: {}\n"
                       "for_h: {}\n"
                       "value: {}\n"
                       "metric: {}\n"
                       "lat_lon: {}\n")
        return baseString.format(for_dt, for_d, for_h, value, metric, lat_lon)

#engine = create_engine('presto://u:p@host:port',connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': 'mypem'}})
#results = engine.execute("select * from 'hive.x.y' limit 1")
results = [(u'2010-02-18 03:00:00.000', u'2010-02-18 00:00:00.000', 3, u'-0.191912651062011660', u'hey', u'there')]

hiveObjects = []

for row in results:
    for_dt = datetime.strptime(row[0], dateTimeFormat)
    for_d = datetime.strptime(row[1], dateTimeFormat)
    for_h = row[2]
    value = Decimal(row[3])
    metric = row[4]
    lat_lon = row[5]

    hiveObjects.append(hivexy(for_dt, for_d, for_h, value, metric, lat_lon))

for hiveObject in hiveObjects:
    print(hiveObject)
```

**Option 2**
This uses reflection - it queries the database metadata for field types so you don't have to do all that stuff in option 1.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *

engine = create_engine('presto://u:p@host:port',connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': 'mypem'}})

# Reflection - SQLAlchemy will get metadata from database including field types
hiveXYTable = Table('hive.x.y', MetaData(bind=engine), autoload=True)
s = select([hiveXYTable]).limit(1)
results = engine.execute(s)

for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Comment: how to run custom SQL query (ie with joins, filters)  not whole Table()

Comment: You will need to read through the SQLAlchemy Expression Language tutorial. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#selecting

Comment: An example join from the tutorial is: s = select([users, addresses]).where(users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id). The where could be used for filtering also, it's fairly intuitive if you know SQL already.

Comment: You can also select single fields just as easily: s = select([users.c.name, users.c.fullname])

Comment: i want to simply have 1 sql string

Comment: You cannot have the type mapping benefits of an ORM without using it. If you want to stick to using sql strings you will need to manage the types yourself by casting/parsing them.

Comment: i don't need ORM, i just want the data type from sql to map to same python data type

Comment: I have updated the answer. You either go with manual parsing of types or use reflection. If option 2 doesn't work (I haven't tested this with your exact presto setup) then it's to do with PyHive. Their website says "Note: query generation functionality is not exhaustive or fully tested, but there should be no problem with raw SQL".